# Retrofitting encryption to .NET rich client application with SOAP messages to back end server

Tags: .net, soap, public-key-encryption

We have an old .NET rich client application connecting to back end services via SOAP using SSL encryption. Simulating an attack,  I have installed Burpsuite on the local machine and intercepted the traffic, modified it and sent it on to the end point (even though it is encrypted with SSL). What is the best way (quickest / cheapest!) to secure the application against this sort of vulnerability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can intercept the unencrypted traffic because Burp does a SSL MITM...if someone can use burp on a machine this means they have high privileges...so it's not a question of application security but system security: low level privilege of the users that are using the client.

You can add another layer of encryption in your rich client, but you need to store the encryption key somewhere in the client and also in the server side. Storing the encryption key in the rich client is not so much secure because it's easy to decompile .NET code or execute it in a debug env to catch the key. Also with an obfuscation layer.

You can evaluate to use asymmetric encryption: a key pair with a public and private keys. You can encrypt secrets with the public key in the rich client and only the server will be able to decrypt them with the private key. But it depends on secrets you want to protect.

Because the asymmetric encryption is slower than the symmetric one, you can encrypt a session symmetric key and share with the server.

But if someone can decompile your rich client they can rewrite your code and do what they wants!